# Use correct colors on QT Quick application running on EGLFS

Tags: qt, qtquick2, egl

I am currently developing a QT Quick application on a BeagleBone.
At the beginning I was running it on a X server, and the way I got the correct colors working was by changing the xorg configuration (super easy), but it was very slow.

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    Option         "ColorSpace" "RGB565"
    DefaultDepth    16
EndSection
```

Now I managed to install the graphics drivers on the BeagleBone and now I can run the application on EGLFS platform with hardware acceleration, but colours are always wrong, and I don't know how to change the EGL configuration, I tried everything.

I'd appreciate any ideas to help me continue with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by modifying the file: `/etc/powervr.ini`:

```
[default]
#WindowSystem=libpvrDRMWSEGL_FRONT.so
WindowSystem=libpvrDRMWSEGL.so
DisableHWTQTextureUpload=0
ParamBufferSize=1677216
DefaultPixelFormat=RGB565
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is also same on BeagleBone but it is like that on RPi,

```
QQuickView view;
QSurfaceFormat currentSurface = view.format();
currentSurface.setRedBufferSize(8);
currentSurface.setGreenBufferSize(8);
currentSurface.setBlueBufferSize(8);
currentSurface.setAlphaBufferSize(0);
view.setFormat(currentSurface);
```

So this way you set EGL to 24bit.